# How to find specific object from list in C#?

Tags: c#, list, search, foreach

How is it possible to find a specific object from a list?
Lets say i have a function that takes an object and a list that contains objects of this type and returns the number at which position the specific object is found.

The only way i could think of a solution is to run the list through with a foreach loop, but isn't there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: be aware that whatever clever function from the library you're using, it basically needs to be implemented as a foreach loop internally - because of the way lists are stored (that is, without indexes). If you have additional structure, for example you know that the data is sorted, you can implement a more efficient algorithm exploiting that information

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IndexOf(T item)` method:

```
myList.IndexOf(myItem);
```

It returns the index of the first occurrence of the item.

Answer (score 0):

You could use linq expressions

```
List.where(condition)
```

Or

```
List.Select(condition).FirstOrDefault
```

Based on search condition it will return the item you want.

Answer (score 0):

To see whether object is there You might just need `List<T>.Contains` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It states,

> Determines whether an element is in the List.

And you need to use it like `List<T>.Contains(T type item)` , where `T` is the same type of `List` and `item` you need to compare. In your case it's a the type of `Object`

And to return the index you can use `List<T>.IndexOf` [Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Searches for the specified object and returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence within the entire List.

Simple Console program

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyType a = new MyType() { id = 10 };
            MyType b = new MyType() { id = 20 };
            MyType c = new MyType() { id = 30 };

            List<MyType> testList = new List<MyType>();

            testList.Add(a);
            testList.Add(b);

            Console.WriteLine(testList.Contains(a)); // <= Will return true
            Console.WriteLine(testList.Contains(c)); // <= Will return false

            Console.WriteLine(testList.IndexOf(a)); // <= will return 0 : the index of object a

            Console.ReadKey();    
        }   
    }

    // A simple class
    class MyType
    {
        private int ID;

        public int id
        {
            get { return ID; }
            set { ID = value; }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The only way i could think of a solution is to run the list through with a `foreach` loop

Generally, you need a loop (a `for` or `foreach`) to find an object in a list. You could use it directly, or through a function that iterates over list elements, but there is going to be a loop. There is no way around it: unless you know something special about the way the elements of the array are arranged, you have to look at them all.

One case of knowing something special about arrangement of elements is knowing that an array is sorted. If this is the case, and when you know the value of the attribute on which the element is sorted, you can find the element much faster by using binary search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `IndexOf` or if you use a special condition then you can use method

```
public int FindIndex(Predicate<T> match);
```

where match is delegate

```
public delegate bool Predicate<T>(T obj);
```

In fact it is similar to standard C++ algorithm `std::find_if`